# Having a lot of issues replacing non-breaking whitespace in a string vb.net/asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

On a string, I have to add some whitespace to a string for padding purposes like so:

```
Dim whiteSpace As Char = CChar(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;"))
tempDisplay.Append(whiteSpace, paddingNeeded)
```

Will give me something like:

```
A99      - More Text
```

Now later, I need to remove that space. I've tried:

```
Dim indexOfDash As Integer = curLinkBtn.Text.IndexOf("-")
Dim testForWhiteSpace As Integer = indexOfDash - 2
Dim whiteSpace As String = " "c 'This and nbsp are both in just to see if they would work
Dim nbsp As Char = CChar(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("&nbsp;"))

'See if there has been whitespace injected at all
 If Char.IsWhiteSpace(curLinkBtn.Text(testForWhiteSpace)) Then
         Dim regReplave As String = Regex.Replace(curLinkBtn.Text, whiteSpace, "!", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) 
         'That produces A99      -!More!Text 
         Dim regReplaveNbsp As String = Regex.Replace(curLinkBtn.Text, nbsp, "*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
         'On this I don't even get the '*'
         curLinkBtn.Text = regReplave
         Dim testChar As Char = curLinkBtn.Text(testForWhiteSpace)
 End If
```

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `\s` (shorthand for whitespace) instead of `" "c:`

```
Dim input = "A99      -&nbsp;More Text"
Dim pattern = "\s|(&nbsp;)"
Dim result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "!")
' produces "A99!!!!!!-!More!Text"
```

This also works for tab characters:

```
Dim input = "A99    -&nbsp;More Text" ' uses a tab character
' produces "A99!-!More!Text"
```

Technically, if your string is decoded, the `&nbsp;` in that regex pattern doesn't really, matter, but I threw it in there for good measure.

Alternatively, if you only wanted to wipe the whitespace around the hyphen, you could just change the regex to search around it and replace it with a plain hyphen in the Regex.Replace:

```
Dim input = "A99          -&nbsp;More Text"
Dim pattern = "(\s|(&nbsp;))*-(\s|(&nbsp;))*"
Dim result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "-")
' produces "A99-More Text"
```

Comment: Did you try this code? Whitespaces are usually ignored by HTML.

Comment: Yes, I tried it in a .NET environment. The question was about removing whitespace server-side.

Comment: Ok, but the way he adds them is using &nbsp. That's why I asked :)

Comment: @valverij That's just what I needed.